# Does Timatic information grant you the right to get on a flight?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, check-in, timatic

I've the residence permit in country A that will expire in a week. I asked for it's prolongation on time but I'm pretty sure that administration of my country of residence will not replace it in time.

In two weeks I need to go to a country B for a several days.

To go to country B I don't need any visa, my passport is enough to stay there. As for return, my passport is not enough and I need visa (residence permit in my case).

In Timatic I read that I *can travel with expired residence permit if I can provide a receipt that I asked for it's prolongation* (I have this receipt).

But is this info really sure and grants me to take a flight back? I read some horrible stories that airline staff had never seen these "prolongation receipts" and sometimes doesn't allow to take a flight.

Is it possible to prove something to airline staff if I print visa requirements from, for example, emirates.com (I have another airline but I didn't found visa requirements section on their site)?

What should I do if they say that my residence permit is expired and my boarding is denied?

Comment: What did the airline say when you asked them about this?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately airline staff can mis-interpret Timatic.  To mitigate this, you can arrive early in case you need to ask for another Agent to review the rules or contact their internal support.  However, be aware that if the airline staff is not satisfied, they can deny you boarding.

Comment: By phone airline says that it's ok. But I call to their central office, my friend told me that agents in country B sometimes had their own opinion when you show them rare documents that they've never seen, and one time his friend did not got to a plane due to this.

Comment: Taking the question literally, *nothing* grants you the right to be on a flight, as airline staff (and the captain in particular) can always deny you boarding.

Comment: FYI: [If an airline erroneously refuses to check in a passenger on the grounds of incomplete paperwork (eg visa), is the passenger entitled to compensation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156700/1810)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest problem is countries where English is rarely spoken (in Russia, for example, check-in staff often doesn't know it), because of Timatic only being in English.

I would advise you to print a Timatic extract (the Emirates search engine is also Timatic) and **underline the relevant section with a pen**.

While check-in staff is normally supposed to rely on Timatic, they do often misinterpret requirements, especially at some airports (Zurich, for example, is full of complete noobs).

So by all means arrive early, and don't be afraid to ask for the supervisor.

Comment: *"check-in staff is obliged to rely on Timatic"* Citation needed.

Comment: *Zurich is full of complete noobs* [citation needed]

Comment: @Jan Personal experience, **lots** of it

Comment: @fkraiem Was told this by Swissport by e-mail

Comment: And that satisfied you? You'd do a terrible lawyer...

Comment: @fkraiem what else would they go by?

Comment: @fkraiem the obligation is probably imposed by the employer, not by any law.  So if Swissport is the employer, there's not much more to be said.

Comment: There have been multiple cases of people denied boarding on flights to China because airline personnel did not understand the transit without visa rules--and that's with native speakers of English who either did not understand or simply refused to even look.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Definitely a strong case of compensation. Had that happen to me as well (them not wanting to look). A Swissport hag at ZRH tried to nonchalantly turn me away from an Airberlin flight to Kosovo because she wouldn't accept my Swedish ID card. I told her several times to look in Timatic - the fourth time I got really irritated and raised my voice, saying I **was** going on that flight, whereby her supervisor showed up. I told him what her problem was, whereby he checked Timatic and let me onboard.

Comment: Yeah, compensation should be due.  That doesn't change the fact that the people didn't get on the flight they should have been allowed on.