# If an airline erroneously refuses to check in a passenger on the grounds of incomplete paperwork (eg visa), is the passenger entitled to compensation?

Tags: visas, air-travel, legal, airlines, compensation

If an airline erroneously refuses to check in a passenger on the grounds of missing/incomplete paperwork (e.g., visa-related such as related in this [post](https://forum.thaivisa.com/topic/856730-border-run-alternatives/page/112/?tab=comments#comment-15227802)) whereas the passenger actually had all the proper paperwork, is the passenger entitled to compensation?

Comment: This question should be fleshed out to show that the passenger had the proper paperwork that *should* have been accepted by the airline. Then it would be a case of **liability** of the airline, probably based on the specifics  of the contract. That would then be a question for [Law Stack Exchange](https://law.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @MarkJohnson in what case should proper paperwork not be accepted by the airline?

Comment: If I read the link properly: the regulations had changed. The passenger had the correct paperwork based on the changed regulation. The IATA data (that the airline relies on) did not reflect this change. The airline refused boarding based on (no longer correct) IATA data. Who is liable? Is this how you read this?

Comment: @MarkJohnson I'm looking for the more general case where the airline incorrectly refuses a check-in based on what paperwork the check-in counter employees thought were required, regardless of whether IATA data was out-of-date or incorrect. In the linked example it is unclear whether the issue was the IATA data, the airline employees who didn't read the information properly, or something else.

Comment: So it boils down to: The airline got it wrong. Who is liable? I think the final answer will depend heavly on the terms of the contract, that may differ from airline to airline.

Comment: I would point out with respect to the question raised by @MarkJohnson that *if* there is liability to the passenger for incorrectly denied boarding, and the reason for the denied boarding is incorrect information in TIMATIC, then it is still the airline that is liable to the passenger. TIMATIC may be liable to the airline, but the passenger doesn't have to be concerned with that.

Comment: @phoog The big issue is satisfying the airline of the fact that TIMATIC is wrong, as they usually see no reason to doubt its accuracy. When I was denied boarding at Sabiha Gökcen for a Bergamo flight, I had the Bergamo border police message the Pegasus back office, but they initially said they assumed the police were lying (yep, they expressed it that way!). Took me 30 miinutes to nagging to talk sense into them, whereby I was re-booked for free, and could claim €400 in compensation much later

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - the bottom line answer is airlines have wiggle room in their legal language. If they *reasonably* suspect you will be denied entry, they are in the clear. Only a legal battle could win that fight - and *you and I" would lose every time.

Comment: @Fattie and the upper bound of how much airlines can screwed passengers is the law, which in the EU at least seems to have some usefulness. That'd be interesting to see the jurisprudence.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - again WRT JBentley's excellent answer, there is perhaps "a bit less" wiggle room in "what the government says" - but unfortunately big companies win "wiggle room" arguments every time.  :/  Signed, yours cynically

Comment: Love the person on that thread who didn't see his country on the selection list for an e-visa, so _he just picked a different one_ and apparently saw no problem with this until people pointed out he could be jailed for it. This explains a lot about the world. (Yes, I know the latter is a territory of the former.)

Comment: @Fattie I'm confused.  JBentley's answer says nothing about third parties.  If anyone is liable to the passenger it is the airline and only the airline.  If the airline has engaged the services of TIMATIC and incurred liability to a passenger because of erroneous information from TIMATIC, then the airline may have a claim against TIMATIC.  The passenger's claim is against the airline.

Comment: @JBentley the third party has no liability to the passenger. They have a contract with the airline.  Information services are not manufactured goods, and furthermore the passenger does not consume TIMATIC's information service, so *Donoghue* does not apply.

Comment: @phoog Fair enough, I didn't mean to imply that it was applicable in this case, just that it isn't an automatic principle that third parties cannot be liable. I will withdraw my earlier comment as it was unclear.

Comment: hi @phoog , I may have misunderstood your comment and/or addressed the wrong person - these chains can become confusing :) - I simply deleted my comment anyway, thank you

Comment: I believe @markmayo mentioned that if you are certain of being right you should be able to sign a document dispensing the airline of repatriating you at their own cost should you not be allowed within the destination country. I believe this very much impacts any claim to compensation: if you do not sign such a document, are you not essentially admitting that you are not sure to have the proper paperwork?

Comment: @MatthieuM. If I were an airline executive, I would not accept that document unless it also promised to reimburse the company for the fine it would receive from the destination country, if any, and I would probably also want evidence that the passenger would be capable of effecting that reimbursement (or better yet, a deposit from the passenger to be refunded if there is no fine).  That's a lot of administrative overhead for a circumstance that presumably arises relatively infrequently.

Answer (score 36):

For flights originating from or destined for the EU, the [Flight Compensation Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation) [(Regulation (EC) No 261/2004)](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32004R0261&from=FR) provides for compulsory compensation from airlines which deny boarding. It cannot be contractually overridden.

[This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/156706/13208) suggests that an airline may be able to rely on phrases such as *"determines at its reasonable discretion"* contained within its contract. I believe that is incorrect for EU cases. The important thing is whether the airline's action is justified under the provisions of the Regulation, not whether it is justified according to its contract.

Article 2(J) provides the following definition:

> "denied boarding" means a **refusal to carry passengers on a flight**,
>   although they have presented themselves for boarding under the
>   conditions laid down in Article 3(2), **except** where there are
>   reasonable grounds to deny them boarding, such as reasons of health,
>   safety or security, or **inadequate travel documentation**;

Article 3(2) states that:

> [The Regulation] shall apply on the condition that passengers: have a
>   confirmed reservation on the flight concerned and, except in the case
>   of cancellation referred to in Article 5, present themselves for
>   check-in, as stipulated and at the time indicated in advance and in
>   writing (including by electronic means) by the air carrier, the tour
>   operator or an authorised travel agent,or, if no time is indicated,
>   not later than 45 minutes before the published departure time.

Article 4(3):

> If boarding is denied to passengers against their will, the operating
>   air carrier shall immediately compensate them in accordance with
>   Article 7 and assist them in accordance with Articles 8 and 9.

Note the subtle difference between e.g. British Airways *"reasonably believing"* there is no travel documentation and the Regulation's requirement that there be *"reasonable grounds [such as] inadequate travel documentation"*. With the latter the court will be looking to see whether or not the travel documentations you presented were in fact adequate, as opposed to what BA reasonably believed was the case.

Note: the answers generated by this question would suggest it is probably a better fit for https://law.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I agree that a passenger refused boarding in a situation controlled by EU Regulation 261/2004 is in a far superior position to one whose complaint is founded in US or US state law.

Comment: It's worth noting that Lufthansa was the only airline I examined in my answer that is (currently) based in an EU member state, and it was also the only one without a clause concerning the airline's "reasonable belief" or some such.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert There was also BA, which is EU based and does have the "reasonable belief" clause.

Comment: @JBentley:  Not as of the end of January.  :-)  I think EU laws still apply officially during the "transition period", though, so your point is taken.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I suspect that the reasonable belief clause is there because of liability law in one or more UK jurisdictions.  The regulation does not forestall additional liability claims under national law.  If the airline's belief that the documents are insufficient is reasonable then the airline may have satisfied its duty of care to the passenger. On the other hand, if the airline claims that even an unreasonable belief would protect it then the clause may be unenforceable altogether.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert All EU law passed up until exit day [remains in force](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2018/16/crossheading/retention-of-existing-eu-law/enacted) even *after* the transitional period, until such time as the UK government decides (on a law by law basis) to repeal it. Quite rightly too - can you imagine the chaos and legal uncertainty if decades worth of laws suddenly vanished overnight!

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Also, to clarify what I meant by "EU based" (which was admittedly not a very good way of phrasing it), it is not relevant where the airline has its headquarters. What matters is whether the flight goes into or out of an EU member state (Article 3(1) of the Regulation).

Answer (score 13):

To answer somewhat indirectly: someone who is in this situation is probably better off initiating a dispute with their credit card company (assuming the tickets were purchased with a credit card).

Some years ago I was denied boarding on a flight, for a reason I didn't understand at the time, and can only guess at now. Afterwards, when it came time to look into a refund, the airline said we should contact the travel agent, and (of course) the travel agent said we should contact the airline. After getting nowhere, I called the credit card company. They refunded my money immediately, said they would deal with it, and I never heard another thing about it.

(In hindsight, I believe the person at the airline counter made a mistake, caused a delay, and was then unable to check us in within the security window. But of course no one ever admitted to this, and importantly, by dealing with the credit card company directly, I never even had to know the truth, much less get someone to accept responsibility for what happened.)

Answer (score 12):

Let's dissect this a bit.

1. The passenger is responsible for having proper documentation.
2. The airline is held accountable by many countries to NOT present passengers at their border that don't meet entry requirements. Accountable = heavy fines!
3. Note that the opposite is NOT true: countries typically don't care whether passengers with right of entry are denied boarding. Example: a US citizen with an expired passport can not be denied entry to the US but no airline will let you board.
4. This creates a strong bias of the airlines to err on the side of denial and typically the contract of carriage contain a fair bit of verbiage around this and what happens if it goes wrong.
5. Airlines typically use Timatic to determine paperwork requirements. Most passengers don't have access so they need to rely on websites and other resources. As far as I know, neither source is liable for the information they provide.

Now let's look at your actual case

> If an airline erroneously refuses

First you would need to determine why this is "erroneous"? Unless the airline has made a mistake and admits to it, you are looking at two conflicting sources of information. You would need a legal authority with proper standing to take a look at the conflict and determine what interpretation is correct. Timatic can be wrong or outdated. Government websites can be wrong and outdated. Happens all the time.

Overall it's less relevant whether the denial was "erroneous" but whether the airline was within their rights to deny you boarding given the paperwork you presented and the information available to them.

> is the passenger entitled to compensation

Let's assume the airline has accepted that their decision was wrong. Next steps depend on what't in the terms and condition of the ticket or the contract of carriage. Most airlines would probably give you a refund or some travel credit claiming it to be "good will". Any type of compensation beyond that is highly unlikely unless the airline was grossly negligent or malicious AND they don't think they can cover it up.

Comment: Looking at the contract alone is not sufficient. You must also look at any applicable laws which may override the contract.

Comment: I have heard of multiple cases where it is clearly erroneous--agents who believe they know that you have to have a visa for China and refuse to check in passengers who don't, even when it is pointed out they have an itinerary that is compliant with China's transit-without-visa rules.  The problems have come from agents at secondary airports.

Comment: Even when they look it up in TIMATIC they can reach the wrong conclusion.  Los Angeles -> Shanghai (5 days) -> Tokyo (3 hours) -> Los Angeles is legal for most passports (Chinese rules see this as USA -> China -> Japan), but you have to enter it into the computer as a flight to Tokyo with a 5-day stopover in Shanghai to get the correct answer.

Comment: [Why would airlines not let a US citizen with an expired passport board a plane?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156755/1810)

Comment: "Example: a US citizen with an expired passport can not be denied entry to the US but no airline will let you board."  [citation needed]  It's not clear to me why you think a US citizen with an expired passport can't be denied entry to the US.  Perhaps you mean "a US citizen who can prove his citizenship", but how is he going to prove it without a valid passport?

Answer (score 10):

I looked at the contracts of carriage of four major airlines, from four different countries:  United, British Airways, Japan Airlines, and Lufthansa.  Three of them allow for the airline to refuse boarding to any passenger whom the airline **reasonably believes** does not have valid travel documents, whether or not they are correct in this belief.

The fourth (Lufthansa) does not appear to have any such clause.  The clause only appears to cover cases where the passenger does not have appropriate documents, not where the airline believes they do not have such documents.

Whether or not a belief is "reasonable" is one of those things that lawyers get paid lots of money to haggle over in court.  Suffice it to say that it will depend on the particular circumstances of each case, and on the case law of the jurisdiction where action is brought.

---

The bolding in the quotes below is mine.

[**United:**](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/contract-of-carriage.html#tcm:76-6638)

> **UA also reserves the right to deny boarding to any Passenger whose necessary travel documents are not in good condition according to UA's reasonable belief,** or which otherwise do not comply with laws of the specific country the Passenger is departing from, transiting through, or traveling to.

[**British Airways:**](https://www.britishairways.com/en-us/information/legal/british-airways/general-conditions-of-carriage)

> We may decide to refuse to carry you or your baggage if one or more of the following has happened **or we reasonably believe may happen.**
>
> ...
>
> 7a15) If you have not, or do not appear to have, valid travel documents.
>
> 7a16) If you try to enter a country for which your travel documents are not valid.
>
> 7a17) If the immigration authority for the country you are travelling to, or for a country in which you have a stopover, has told us (either orally or in writing) that it has decided not to allow you to enter that country, even if you have, or appear to have, valid travel documents.

[**Japan Airlines:**](https://www.jal.co.jp/en/inter/carriage/)

> 10. JAL may refuse Carriage of, or remove, any Passenger, and in such case his/her Baggage will be handled in the same way, **if JAL determines at its reasonable discretion** that: ...
>
> (3) (a) the Passenger falls under sub-paragraph (1) (b) of paragraph (B) of Article 16,
>
> ...
>
> 16. (B) Passports and Visas
>
> (1)
>
> (a) A Passenger shall present to JAL all exit, entry or other necessary documents required by Applicable Laws of country concerned such as countries to be flown from, into or over, and shall permit JAL, if JAL at its reasonable discretion deems it necessary, to make and retain copies thereof; provided that, even if a Passenger presents exit, entry or other necessary documents to JAL and JAL carry the Passenger, JAL shall not be deemed to guarantee that such documents comply with Applicable Laws.
>
> (b) JAL reserves the right to refuse Carriage of any Passenger who does not comply in any respect with any of such Applicable Laws or whose exit, entry or other necessary documents are not complete in any respect.

[**Lufthansa:**](https://www.lufthansa.com/xx/en/business-terms-and-conditions-1#7)

> 7.1 ... [W]e may also refuse to carry you or continue to carry you or cancel your seat reservation if ...
>
> 7.1.7.  you are not in possession of a valid travel document; you wish to enter a country for which you are only entitled as a transit passenger or for which you do not possess valid immigration documents; you destroy your travel documents during the flight; or you refuse to give your travel documents to a member of the crew against a receipt when asked to do so; or

Comment: I would assume that it violates or is in conflict with consumer protection legislation in many jurisdictions that an airline (or any company for that matter) can withdraw unilaterally from a contract just based on beliefs and assumptions, no matter how reasonable these assumptions are.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The airline is not withdrawing unilaterally from the contract. Instead, the airline relies on the contract language to avoid liability; the language was agreed-to by the passenger at purchase. If consumer protection law expressly provided passenger protection, then the legislation would indeed render the contract language unenforceable, and the passenger could be protected. I'm a retired lawyer in the US, however, and I've never seen such provisions in US or state law, nor have I seen such specific protections in any discussion here of EU or other foreign law.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica In the EU the [Flight Compensation Regulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation) is a well known example of such a consumer protection law. It cannot be contractually overriden. More generally, consumer protection laws tend to be more widely adopted in Europe than the US, so the principle that the "contract is king" is a weaker one over here. I've posted an answer to give an alternative viewpoint to this one.