# Why would airlines not let a US citizen with an expired passport board a plane back to the US?

Tags: usa, air-travel, passports

[Hilmar](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/13971/hilmar) wrote in [one of their answers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/156704/1810):

> a US citizen with an expired passport can not be denied entry to the US but no airline will let you board.

His first statement is supported by https://www.aclunc.org/our-work/know-your-rights/know-your-rights-us-airports-and-ports-entry

> U.S. citizens cannot be denied entry to the U.S. for any reason, including for refusing to produce passwords, provide device access, or submit electronic devices for a search. Lawful permanent residents cannot be refused entry unless their travel was not brief (more than 180 days) or they engaged in illegal activity after leaving the United States as defined in 8 U.S.C. 1101(a)(13).

Why would airlines not let a US citizen with an expired passport board a plane?

(Assume the US citizen doesn't have a REAL ID driver license, or some other document that airlines would accept.)

Comment: 'Why' questions are not the right kind for Stack Exchange as we users can not see in the heads of the people who decide on the decisions.

Comment: @Willeke There are plenty of Why questions on Stack Exchange. People who "decide on the decisions" sometimes also use Internet, and also may have stated somewhere their reasons for their decisions.

Comment: You know the underlying why, the Database the airlines do base their decisions on do not mention that without a valid passport you could be allowed into the USA. But I bet you want an answer that explains why those airlines do not go round the database information.

Comment: To discuss something other than the rule the airlines follow, is perhaps a better question "why might a citizen not be allowed a current passport" ?  I can imagine at least one reason in that perhaps they are accused of a crime and their current, unexpired passport is held by a court to block travel.

Comment: I'm not sure how it works in the US but I assume you could renounce citizenship but still have an old expired passport. So it's not clear how you prove citizenship in this scenario

Comment: Renouncing US citizenship means filling out forms and paying high fees at an embassy.  So records exist.  But I doubt gate agents or checkin agents have access to those records.

Comment: @MikeM your example has an issue, in that scenario the loss is to keep you from leaving the country not coming back.  In your example, the country should be happy to get their criminal back.  Unless the country trying to block travel is the country they are currently in?

Comment: @JamesJenkins -- Well, I certainly intended that they are already abroad.  I'm not familiar with the laws in every country, but I think there are multiple countries that might hold a passport.  It isn't necessarily the best example, anyways;  just felt like another direction than the rule details might be interesting.

Answer (score 55):

So this guy rocks up to the airline counter:

> Guy: Here's my US passport.
>
> Airline Employee: It's expired
>
> Guy: Yeah, but it's a legit US passport!  Honest!
>
> AE: You got any other ID?
>
> Guy: Nah, but look at my passport.  It's a genuine US passport!
>
> AE: So you want me to assume that because you are in possession of an expired US
> passport in your name, that you are still eligible to enter the US because you are a citizen.  But you can't provide me with any other proof that would support that assumption?
>
> Guy: Well, yeah.  But look at how shiny and blue the passport is!

This reads like a Monty Python sketch.

While it's true that a US citizen can not be refused entry to the US, how do you expect $RandomAirline to validate that traveller is a current US citizen if all they can proffer up is an expired travel document?

Given that an airline can be [fined](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/23644/6188) for allowing passengers on a flight who are ineligible for admission at a destination, it behooves the airline to reject any passenger who cannot adequately prove who they are or that they have the correct travel documents.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106937/discussion-on-answer-by-peter-m-why-would-airlines-not-let-a-us-citizen-with-an).

Comment: Place your additional comments in the chatroom.

Answer (score 51):

Because the US government wants it this way.

**Rule #1:** The government requires all citizens to travel with a valid passport (or equivalent). See https://www.usa.gov/enter-us

**Rule #2:** CBP (Customs and Border Protection) cannot deny entry to a US citizen: see for example https://www.axios.com/us-citizens-rights-at-the-border-430039f3-724b-4a26-8ad8-976346c95431.html

So what happens if a citizen without passport (or expired passport) shows up at the border? Turns out rule #2 trumps rule #1 and so CPB has to admit them. The government doesn't like that and so they basically use the airlines to enforce rule #1 for them.

Comment: Thanks, "they basically use the airlines to enforce rule #1 for them.". How do they convince/force the airlines to enforce rule #1?

Comment: If it's at the government's behest, in what way does the government prevail upon airlines to enforce that?

Comment: If an international traveler is refused admittance at the destination or transit point, the airline is required to fly the refused traveler back to the point of departure, at the airline's expense (the airline will try to collect this from the passenger, but that's a different issue), and may in addition be fined.   All countries require this of airlines who bring passengers to the country's territory. At least back in the day of full aircraft, this was a powerful disincentive to accept a passenger with less-than-convincing documents.

Comment: The government simply tells the airline what to do and the airline would be stupid not to go along with it. There is nothing for the airline to gain and a lot to loose in picking a fight over this. In some cases the government will levy substantial fines. Travel is a privilege, not a right.

Comment: Rule #1 strikes me as totally unconstitutional, but then those with influence interpret the rules anyway that suits them and whenever it suits them.

Comment: @MaxPower It is entirely constitutional, because the requirement to use a passport is a matter of international treaty, and ratified treaties are federal law per Article II Section 2. The exact limits and interpretations are arcane (not all international agreements are legally considered "treaties"), so best to read up on the "Treaty Clause" elsewhere.

Comment: @choster passports or equivalent IDs are now required for most domestic travel as well. Like I said those with influence can always find a way to manipulate interpretations, whether it is abusing the interstate commerce clause for drug laws or treaties clause to slowly form an American iron curtain.

Comment: @MaxPower You're comparing apples and oranges, as the ID requirements for domestic travel are grounded in different law from passport requirements, but in fact, you don't need an ID to fly. If you lose your ID on the way to the airport, you'll still be able to get on your flight, and of course it's a non-issue for private flights as well. But in any case, this is Travel.SE, not Law.SE, and this back-and-forth demonstrates why "why" questions are generally a bad fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: Another factor is that countries maintain and publish procedures for authenticating current passports, but not for authenticating all passports that they have ever issued.  Suppose a country changed the design of ten-year passports on January 1, 2005 and again on January 1, 2010.  Prior to January 1, 2020, the country would have had to publish advice on how to authenticate 2005-style passports, but it would likely have discontinued such publication since then.  If someone were to show up with a document claiming to be a ten-year-passport issued December 1, 2009, ...

Comment: ...an airline would have no way of validating it.

Comment: It's not that different to claiming asylum. By the international convention on refugees, it's legal to claim asylum if you make it into the country. But it's frequently the case that there are no legal avenues to entering the country in the first place.

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question asks "Why would **airlines** [not the CBP] not let a US citizen with an expired passport **board a plane?"** [not "cross the border"]. With an international flight, the boarding-the-plane part comes thousands of miles before crossing-the-border part (except for countries with US preclearance, like Ireland). Unless the missing part of your answer is "The airlines might potentially get penalized if they transport a passenger who might not get admitted, e.g. forged documents".

Comment: @SteveBennett The late Hans Rosling has an [illuminating 2 minute talk](https://youtu.be/YO0IRsfrPQ4) about the puzzling question why refugees who are perfectly well entitled to fly into the EU in order to apply for asylum instead take the dangerous and more expensive sea route. The answer is that the EU is effectively "outsourcing" the determination of refugee status, a core sovereign duty and privilege, to the airlines. Not to embassy employees, not to customs and border employees, not to the police or military: To the airlines. These decide very conservatively that nobody is a refugee.

Comment: @choster The requirement for *American citizens* to provide an *American passport* (or a driver's license) when demanding entry into the US at an airport *on American soil* is clearly not subject to any international treaties.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt re "How do they force ..." -> The US customs can determine if the traveller is the bona fide holder of the expired passport and whether they are a US citizen. The airline can do neither with confidence. If the airline allows the passenger to travel to the US and the claim is not valid the airline may be fined. Not allowing the passenger to travel is the superior option for the airline. Hey - that's a complete answer :-).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If the airline boards a passenger without a valid form of identification they endanger everyone on the plane and some more. At least that's what a prosecutor can claim. If the person boarded does anything remotely dangerous ([has illness](https://www.independent.co.uk/news/health/coronavirus-testing-denied-us-china-covid-19-massachusetts-a9404366.html), [starts fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_air_rage_incidents) etc) the crew can go to jail. If it's policy, then executive management can go to jail.

Comment: If people don't think a government have power over an airline, think of how China got major airlines to list "Taiwan" as "Taiwan, China" and "Hong Kong" as "Hong Kong, China".

Comment: This answer makes more sense than the one arguing with Monty Python sketchs.

Answer (score 28):

A CBP liaison office has told IATA to write in TIMATIC that a valid passport is required, and TIMATIC is what airlines go by. Whilst entry with an expired US passport can't be refused, the carrier would be heavily fined for transporting the passenger.

Equally, in South Africa, South Africans are legally supposed to have a valid passport; there, failure to comply results in a fine for the passenger as well as the airline.

For many other countries TIMATIC does say expired passports/other proof of citizenship is accepted, even though national law may stipulate you're supposed to have a valid one. In that case a carrier would not be fined, but the passenger might.

For instance, for Bosnia TIMATIC says valid or expired Bosnian passports or ID cards are accepted. However, if using an expired document, or a valid ID card other than if arriving on a direct flight from Belgrade, a Bosnian citizen could receive an administrative fine.

Comment: Please cite evidence that an airline can be fined for delivering a passenger to a location that traveler can legally enter.

Comment: @WGroleau I haven't read anything published about it, but various handling staff and border officers have explained it to me, saying it's due to additional administrative hassle on the part of local authorities.

Comment: Would the airline be fined if the passenger boards the plane with a valid non-American passport, and then presented their expired American passport at the American gate?

Comment: @nick012000 How would they get onboard with a foreign passport, given that neither visas nor ESTAs are issued to US citizens? The only possibilities would be a Canadian, Marshall Islander, Micronesian or Palauan passport, and no, the carrier wouldn't be fined in that case

Comment: The carrier will not be fined for delivering a passenger to a _legal_ destination.  However, if Timatic tells them not to make that delivery, they will likely refuse.

Comment: @WGroleau But it isn't in fact legal to enter the US with an expired US passport, although there's no penalty for it, so in practice the CBP can merely be morons about it and scold you for it. The carrier, however, would be penalised since legally the passenger didn't hold the proper documents.

Comment: Repeating the claim is not evidence.

Comment: @WGroleau Goes both ways. There's no proof AFAIK either in the positive or negative, but at least I've spoken to some people responsible for these matters.

Comment: I didn’t claim proof for anything, I merely asked for evidence.

Comment: Did you mean Belgrade, which is the capital of Serbia, or Sarajevo, the capital of Bosnia?

Comment: @cja I meant Belgrade (Serbia)

Comment: WGroleau A little Google-fu yields numerous reports of governments fining airlines for transporting passengers who were denied entry or transit. The fines are in addition to the airline's responsibility to return the passenger to the point of departure. In some rare cases where there's no return flight quickly, and the passenger must be held at the refusing country for longer than a day or so (and therefore not just in a holding room at the airport's immigration facility), airlines have also been forced to provide overnight accommodation and security.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: I think WGroleau is aware that airlines can be fined for delivering a passenger to a location they **cannot** legally enter. However, Crazydre claims that the airline can be fined even if the passenger **can** legally enter.

Comment: @Jan: WGroleau asked for evidence supporting government authority to fine airlines; I assert this is easily found. I also agree with Crazydre because in practice airline liability is determined by what immigration actually does. Because immigration errs sometimes, airlines are sometimes fined unjustly: while immigration's refusal may be contrary to the receiving country's law, the carrier little muscle to change immigration's refusal. To minimize their exposure, and guard against immigration errors, airlines act very conservatively. Edge cases are unlikely to be allowed to board.

Comment: @Jan "can legally enter" This is the thing: legally a US citizen is usually supposed to have a passport to enter, even though they can't be refused without. When the airline doesn't cooperate with US law in this regard (as reflected in TIMATIC), I've been informed they can get fined. Equally, in South Africa, South Africans are legally supposed to have a valid passport; there, not having one will result in both the passenger and airline being fined.

Comment: @Crazydre: Do you have a source for this (passenger is able to enter but airline has to pay a fine anyway)?

Comment: @Jan Read my first comment

Answer (score 23):

The problem with this scenario is the same one as that person will have at the immigration checkpoint: while the law says that US citizens cannot be denied entry, how does the immigration officer know that they *are*, in fact, a US citizen? Now, the immigration officer has four things that the gate agent does not have:

- Access to the full resources of the US government, so they could, for example, use a birth certificate, driver's license, social security number, etc. to verify that person's identity, and from verifying the identity go on to verify the citizenship status.
- Knowledge of US immigration and citizenship law.
- Time. The law says that US citizens cannot be denied entry, it doesn't say that they can't wait a little bit while their citizenship status is verified.
- Experience in recognizing, reading, interpreting, and verifying various documents that can be used to establish identity or citizenship, such as birth certificates.

The gate agent has none of that. They are not US government agents, they cannot take an arbitrary amount of time (the plane's not waiting, but the other passengers in the queue are!)

How would the person prove to the gate agent that they are, in fact, a US citizen, and do that in a way that is *fast* to verify, *easy* to verify, and *possible* to verify for a random gate agent of a random airline at a random airport in a random country? Where I fly from, some gate agents don't even work for a single airline, they are provided by the airport as a service to the airlines. They might handle an Asiana flight to Seoul right now, an hour later a South African flight to Johannesburg, and then a Delta flight to Atlanta.

Do you expect them to memorize the immigration law of every country on the planet, and be familiar with the citizenship laws of every country on the planet, and be able to recognize, read, interpret, and verify every possible document that can be used to prove every possible citizenship of every country on the planet? Heck, people in the US cannot even agree with each other whether Barack Obama was born in the US or Kenya!

It is simply impractical to expect a gate agent to be able to verify that someone is a US citizen who has no document showing that they are a US citizen.

It is just much easier, and much cheaper, to rely on an automated system that contains a set of simple, easy to follow, and easy to check rules, and that system says that in order for a US citizen to fly to the US, they need a valid passport. The US government *could* have put a different rule in the system, but they decided not to.

Note that there is another aspect that was not mentioned in the question nor in any of the answers so far that has nothing to do with immigration or citizenship: airlines are also, in at least some cases, required to verify the *identity* of their passengers. Typically, travel documents (and certainly passports) also pull double-duty as identity documents. So, even if this hypothetical passenger were allowed to board the plane for *immigration* reasons, they would still need to prove their identity using a valid, internationally recognized identity document … most likely a passport.

Comment: How about accept the fact that the expired passport is still very strong evidence that this is a US Citizen?

Comment: Do you want to be the gate agent that is responsible for letting the next 9/11 hijackers onto a plane just because you thought an invalid passport still looks "good enough"? Do you want to be the airline executive that has to buy insurance for that case? The gate agent is not a Border Patrol officer. They have no training in how to determine whether an invalid US passport is "good enough" or not. They have no access to US government databases to verify the identity and citizenship by means other than the passport.

Comment: I do not want to be the airline who was sued for civil rights violations either.

Comment: Just to give a different example: in order to fly nationally within the US, as a citizen, there are about a dozen different documents you can use. As a foreigner, the only allowed document is a passport. If a US citizen can fly with their driver's license, why can't I? The reason is the same as above: a US gate agent / TSA agent knows how to verify a US driver's license, but not a German one. Passports are internationally standardized, so there's only one additional document they need to learn, not 200 different driver's licenses.

Comment: If you can point me to the Article in the Constitution that says that some random airline on the other site of the globe has to let you fly without valid documentation, I will gladly retract my statement.

Comment: Link's here https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/156756/36100 (goes to other answer on this question)

Comment: @Joshua The link says the CBP have to let you cross the border. It does *not* say the airline has to transport you to the border.

Comment: It is a little bit funny because chances not to be anymore a citizen with expired passport is same as having a non-expited passport. One doesn't lose citizenship because document expired.
More likely bureaucracy/CYA behavior and cases are sufficiently rare that losing customers is not a concern.

Comment: @akostadinov: When you renounce your citizenship, you have to hand in your travel documents. Or report them lost/stolen. Some websites claim that in the US, you do not have to report lost expired passports when applying for a new one. If this is true, you could wait until your passport expires, apply for a new one, and hand in the new one when renouncing your citizenship. I doubt many people would do that, of course. But still it seems much easier to keep an expired passport than a new one (unless you are okay with having the passport in the lost/stolen database)

Answer (score 12):

This is the TL;DR version :-)

US customs can determine if the traveller is the bona fide holder of the expired passport and whether they are a US citizen.

The airline can do neither with confidence.

If the airline allows the passenger to travel to the US and the claim is not valid the airline may be fined.

Not allowing the passenger to travel is the superior option for the airline.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an analogy:  Let us suppose, for a moment, that you are a Season Ticket holder for a local Sports Team.  Today is a *really* important game, and the stadium is going to be packed.

Unfortunately, there was a mix-up with this year's Season Ticket, and it wasn't sent out to you properly.  They'll get it to you as soon as they can, and for today they have a runner waiting to check your ID, and escort you to the VIP box as an apology for the situation.  Nothing can stop you from getting in to watch the game!

Except, your taxi driver is a bit put out by all of the traffic - going all the way there, with zero chance of a return-fare (because everyone is staying to watch the game) isn't going to make them as much money as doing other trips around the city.  However, as a fellow fan of Local Sports Team, your taxi driver *will* take you to the Stadium - **if**, and *only* if, you can show a valid Ticket for the game.

Which, you don't have.

A Season Ticket Holder [Citizen] will not be denied entry to the Stadium [Country].  But, first, they have to *get there*.  And the Taxi Driver [Airline] is under no obligation to take you if they think it will be a waste of both your time.

Comment: Thanks I was hoping that the airline had more means of verification than the fellow fan.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If they *did*, then - personally - I would be distinctly worried about how much personal information about their citizens the United States was willing to casually share with the airline...

Comment: There are services for verifying documents validity.

Comment: @akostadinov How many of them can be carried out from another country, in less than 2 hours?

Comment: @Chronocidal, this is not the point. Not sure why I wrote my first comment. If it is fake, then the user would have set a proper expiry date anyway. What are chances after all for a user to lose citizenship because passport expired? Not more than losing citizenship without passport being expired.

Comment: @akostadinov Most people who lost citizenship will have an expired passport, because they can't get it renewed.  They don't lose citizenship *because* the passport expires - it's the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Being a US citizen, and being able to prove that you're a US citizen, are two different things.

If you show up at the border then, as a citizen, they have to let you in — but only if they actually know that you are a citizen. Otherwise *everybody* in the world could just say "hey guys, I'm a citizen, let me in" and that would be that.

**This is the whole point of identity documents.**

There is no magic, secret handshake that reveals you to be a *bona fide* citizen in the absence of said documents.

So it should not be surprising that when your documents are out of date (effectively, you have no valid evidence of being a citizen), the airline will not take a chance on transporting you.

If you got to the US border with a valid, non-expired passport and CBP did not let you in, *that* would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks. "There is no magic, secret handshake that reveals you to be a bona fide citizen in the absence of said documents." How about fingerprints o face recognition?

Comment: People who haven’t been forced by police (after arrest) to be fingerprinted can’t prove anything by their fingerprints.  And face recognition has been proven unreliable.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt That is not magic either. You can't just scan somebody's face or fingers and magically know that they are a citizen. These are biometric measurements _matched to records on file_. If this cannot be done, you won't be let in. CBP cannot prohibit _somebody they can reasonably know to be a citizen_ to enter the country. That doesn't just mean they wave you in if you say "I'm a citizen". Come on this is obvious

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings  "These are biometric measurements matched to records on file." -> Doesn't the US  have records of face pictures or fingerprints of their citizens? According to WGroleau at least some citizens gave their fingerprints. "Come on this is obvious" -> please don't assume that anyone in the world is familiar with the US. Only 5% of people live there.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Yes, so, if there are records, congratulations you can get in. Do the airlines have access to the national citizen face database? Of course not. It's not obvious because of anything to do with the US. I know very little about the US. I don't live there either. My point is that your question is asking why airlines don't just _take your word for it_ on being a citizen. The answer is... why on earth would they?? End of story, really.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings My question is not asking "why airlines don't just take your word for it on being a citizen".

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In what way is it not? It is premised on your expectation that airlines would accept an expired passport as a valid travel document, because CBP need to be able to let in [proven] citizens. That's literally what your question says. That's a question formed by two _non sequiturs_ back to back from an established, high rep user, which is kind of weird to me to be honest. Have a good day.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt may I ask why you insist on being so argumentative, *in comments*? You're the asker here. Don't like this answer? Don't select it. Really don't like it? Down vote it. As this answerer points out in comments, you are a high rep user. Please stop using comments as chat. You should *know better*

Comment: @CGCampbell I've actually upvoted this answer :) My comments were not chatty though but instead asking about some points of the answer.  The answerer was kind enough to give some feedback, and the discussion ended.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other answers seem to address why a person with an expired US passport might not be a US citizen.

Here are two reasons:

1. After the passport expired, the individual did something which caused an automatic loss of US citizenship.  [Here's a list of possibilities.](https://www.usa.gov/renounce-lose-citizenship)  Generally these things don't *immediately* result in a loss of citizenship; there would be a court hearing.
2. After the passport expired, the individual *intentionally* lost his/her US citizenship by obtaining another citizenship, and then [renouncing his/her US citizenship before a US consular officer](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/legal/travel-legal-considerations/Advice-about-Possible-Loss-of-US-Nationality-Dual-Nationality.html).

The airline has no way of knowing whether an expired passport indicates a loss or renunciation of citizenship, or whether the person merely forgot to renew.  The airline has to err on the side of caution by not allowing into the United States a person who might not legally be able to be there.

Answer (score 1):

Airlines are not able to track what the *actual* requirements for crossing a border are. These requirements change, are sometimes really unclear, and sometimes quite ideosyncratic. Airlines have to rely on databases (timatic) that do this job for them. If the database says that your documentation is insufficent, and they have no evidence to the contrary, they will deny boarding (in order to avoid possible fines, as mentioned elsewhere).

I am familiar with a smallish country where it was - over years - possible (and legally possible) to get a visa at the border, even though timatic said otherwise. If you were flying with *their* national carrier, there was no problem relying on this, because there was always some representative from the airline in the vicinity of the gate who would confirm that these people could board. But if you were relying on getting a visa-on-arrival and were flying some other airline, possibly on a non-direct flight - well, bad luck for you.

This situation is rather similar to the one the OP describes in that entry was legally possible, but this was not reflected in the references available to the airlines.

P.S. as for why the CBP would tell timatic that people can only board with valid passports, I suspect there is some practical reason. E.g. higher incidence of people using someone else's expired passport. Or people misplacing their old passport, reporting it as stolen and then forgetting about it. When travelling in a foreign country, would you rather be told "Your cannot board that plane because your passport is expired. Please visit your embassy." or "You cannot board that plane because you are travelling on a passport that has been reported stolen. Please call a lawyer."?

Comment: So there was an actual airline representative in a (to them) foreign country?

Comment: I do not know what the actual job title of that guy was. Maybe agent would be a better fit.. He was an employee of the airline (not of the airport or some local airport service company)  and was able to make decisions about tickets, who gets on the plane etc. The airline has an office with a few employees from their country in my country (which I find unsurprising), and he is probably one of them.

Comment: Ah K, I've only seen that with a few major airlines e.g. Aeroflot and Turkish Airlines. IME the handling agents are usually on their own.