# Renewing my Passport

Tags: usa, passports, filipino-citizens

I am currently in the USA, locked down do to the Covid-19 pandemic. I am from the Philippines, my Passport will expire in August. Do I have to renew my Philippines Passport before I can travel back to the Philippines?

Comment: Most certainly yes. Even though the Philippines will allow entry of Nationals of the Philippines who reside in the Philippines with an expired passport, IMHO it is unlikely any airline will allow you to board with an expired passport. You may also have issues with TSA unless you have another form of valid ID, or two secondary forms of identification.

Comment: Do you expect to travel before your passport expires?

Comment: No travel until after the passport has expired

Comment: FYI [Why would airlines not let a US citizen with an expired passport board a plane back to the US?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156755/1810)

Comment: This has to do with my wife who is here in the USA who is a Philippines Citizen and a Philippines Passport that is about to expire July 31st!