# Where can I view Timatic information for a given day in the past?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, online-resources, history, timatic

Where can I access [Timatic information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timatic) for a given day in the past? E.g. see Timatic information when flying from country X to country Y on date yyyy-mm-dd.

From what I can see searching for a destination on https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/ only shows the current information. Since [Timatic gets "75+ updates daily"](https://youtu.be/M96-3Qh_I6E?t=20) one would ideally be able to also indicate the time in the day to be precise.

Comment: I'm not sure there is such a thing! I suggest screenshotting and printing.

Comment: What use would such information be?

Comment: @Arthur'sPass Every so often it does come up, e.g. when someone is denied boarding, and wants to look up what Timatic said on the day they were supposed to fly.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass (e.g. [If an airline erroneously refuses to check in a passenger on the grounds of incomplete paperwork (eg visa), is the passenger entitled to compensation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/156700/1810))

Comment: I guess this is far from a public info and that only a paying customer of TIMATIC *may* have access to it

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to access Timatic information for a given day in the past. The only option is to check the current information for your intended travel date and destination. This is because the Timatic system is constantly updated with current information on visa and entry requirements, travel advisories, and other relevant travel information. Therefore, it is not possible to access historical Timatic data for a specific date and time.