# What rights do airlines have to deny boarding due to immigration issues?

Tags: visas, airlines

So I just stumbled across [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/hibcoe/i_have_been_denied_travel_and_i_dont_know_what_to/) account of a traveller which I can imagine to be pretty distressing
because I myself have had a rather close call not too long ago. I was travelling from Singapore travelling to Switzerland (to which I can travel visa-free) and a recent relaxation of regulation allows me to apply for a residency permit only after landing in Switzerland, instead of having to apply at the Swiss embassy in Singapore. Thus I travelled to the airport without any visa and the airline did not want to let me board because I did not have a swiss residency permit on hand (yet) or a return ticket. However I insisted that based on my own research I shouldn't already need a residency permit to enter the country, but the airline was firm on their stance. I argued with the manager for a while and eventually they let me board after I provided enough evidence that I had sufficient reason to be living in Switzerland and as a result I almost missed my flight.

My question is, to what extent do airlines have the right to reject people from boarding due to immigration issues at the destination country? My logic is that even if I landed in Switzerland without a residency permit and don't manage to acquire the necessary documents then, it should be the responsibility of the Swiss immigrations to kick me out of their country, and not the airline's (which isn't even swiss airlines)?

Anyway, it turned out in the end that I acquired my residence documents successfully in the country, so the airline would have done me a great disservice had they successfully barred me from boarding the plane.

Comment: I feel the two answers so far are practical, but don't address the underlying question: What recourse does a passenger have if the airline's judgment on this is wrong? I doubt it's truly "absolutely none". For example, if the airline denies boarding due to overbooking, they usually have to provide compensation. If they deny boarding due to immigration issues, they may not even have to refund the airfare. So could an airline solve an overbooking problem by falsely claiming there are immigration issues? What prevents such abuse?

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I realise after writing, that this question is actually the heart of what i was trying to get at.

Comment: @krubo: The airlines rely on an automated system whose rules are provided by the governments themselves. So, in this particular case, the Swiss government has put a rule in the automated system that tells the airlines they are not allowed to let someone without a residency permit board. There's really not much the airline can do about that.

Comment: I read some more about the issue of one way tickets I guess my confusion stemmed from how the rules regarding this are often inconsistently applied. I have been to switzerland twice and both times i expected to stay there for an extended period of time. Both times i bought one way tickets and provided proof of the documents I was going to submit to the consulate there to obtain a permit. The first time i was let on board (and many of my colleagues in the same situation were too) The second time i was refused boarding unless i bought a return ticket.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag. I suppose I didn't word my question properly. I was not so much asking whether they have the right; its their plane of course they do, rather to what extent this right extends. E.g. of course an airline has the right to deny a passenger from boarding purely based on skin colour. But I'm sure that they may be facing legal issues afterward should the passenger sue. So yea, my question was more on the recourse.

Comment: If you "didn't word my question properly," then why not edit it?

Comment: @krubo the answer to that question is quite simple - whatever the local laws say.  For an EU based airline or an airline flying from the EU, where the traveller presents with all the right documentation and is still denied boarding for incorrect documentation, the airline must pay compensation and offer a refund or a different flight.  Other jurisdictions may have similar rules.  Other jurisdictions may exempt the airline from any liability at all. You also have the option to sue the airline in many jurisdictions.  Key here is jurisdiction - its a legal question with many different answers.

Comment: Related: [If an airline erroneously refuses to check in a passenger on the grounds of incomplete paperwork (eg visa), is the passenger entitled to compensation?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/156700/if-an-airline-erroneously-refuses-to-check-in-a-passenger-on-the-grounds-of-inco)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Airlines, in general, have an absolute right to deny boarding. But in the case of  immigration issues, they frequently have an *obligation* to check whether passengers can be admitted to the destination. Many countries will levy fines on airlines who deliver a passenger to their border who is lacking required documents.

Every country implements this differently, but it is common practice that airlines must either take responsibility for removing the inadmissable passenger, at their own expense, or pay a fee or fine to the government if they're unable to do so.

In Switzerland, [the law is as follows](https://www.admin.ch/opc/en/classified-compilation/20020232/index.html#id-ni12-2):

> Air carriers transporting persons must take all reasonable measures to ensure that they only transport persons who possess the required travel documents, visas and residence documents to enter the Schengen area or to travel through international transit zones of the airports.

> 1. The air carrier is obliged at the request of the competent federal or cantonal authorities to provide immediate assistance to any passengers that it is carrying who are denied entry to the Schengen area.
> 2. The obligation to provide assistance covers:
>
>    1. the immediate transport of the person concerned from Switzerland to their country of origin, to the state issuing the travel documents or to another state where their admission is guaranteed;
>    2. the uncovered costs of the required attendance as well as the customary subsistence and care costs until departure from or entry into Switzerland.
> 3. If the air carrier is unable to provide evidence that it has fulfilled its duty of care, it must additionally bear
>
>    1. the uncovered subsistence and care costs that have been covered by the Confederation or the canton for a period of stay of up to six months, including the costs for detention under the law on foreign nationals;
>    2. the attendance costs;
>    3. the deportation costs.

Comment: I am going to travel to Switzerland again and I would like to avoid another case of the above happening. My residency permit expires in end August and I will be renewing it over there. Now, if I buy a one way ticket into Switzerland in August, with a permit expiring end August (to be renewed) and without a return ticket, could they possibly bar me from boarding again due to the "lack of guarantee" that I will be able to reside there legally beyond August?

Comment: @ZhanfengLim Since you must apply for renewal before the permit expires, you will arrive in Switzerland while the permit is valid. This *should* not cause any problem with the airline (but of course one never knows with some airlines).

Comment: By this logic, I _should_ also have been allowed to board in my first encounter as we have visa-free entry for 90 days, but was denied because I couldn't provide evidence of what would happen beyond that (will I successfully get my permit or will I fly back?). Since my permit would only be valid for one month after landing in switzerland, I could see this possibly becoming a problem for the airline staff.

Comment: @ZhanfengLim Airlines use databases of entry requirements to assess whether passengers should be allowed to board. To be honest, since you are eligible for visa free travel to Switzerland, I'm surprised you were denied boarding the first time (and it seems to have been a mistake or misunderstanding of the entry requirements). With your residence permit you are certainly eligible for entry, so the airline has no risk of being required to remove you. Of course, I can't guarantee how things will go for you.

Comment: A subtle but important point: this answer's lead paragraph speaks of travelers who are "ineligible for entry," but the law actually only considers the question of whether travelers "possess the required travel documents, visas and residence documents."  This distinction is significant because it means that the airlines don't have to look past the documents into travelers' purpose of travel or, more intrusively, other private matters such as criminal history.  If someone with a visa is denied because of criminal history, the airline is not liable for a fine.

Comment: @phoog I wasn't trying to draw any distinction (and to point out, the Swiss law I'm quoting is a non-binding translation). In my mind "ineligible for entry" means someone who could never be admitted, due to lacking appropriate documents etc, but I'm not a lawyer, and perhaps you have a better wording.

Comment: @Zhangfen Lim Timatic, the database used by airlines, notes “Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.“ https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true So yes, without your permit and without a return ticket you could face a problem at check-in

Comment: Presumably, this could just be a bus or train ticket from Switzerland to a neighbouring country. You could buy this on your phone at check in if the staff have an issue with it.

Comment: @MJeffryes All of the neighboring countries are also in the Schengen Area. You will normally be put back on a plane and flown back to your point of origin if you're denied entry at an airport (not just in Switzerland, but almost anywhere.) For the Schengen Area, they'll normally want to see a return ticket _leaving the Schengen Area_, since the whole thing is effectively considered one big country for purposes of immigration control.

Comment: "Airlines, in general, have an absolute right to deny boarding." Airlines face hefty fines for significant *delays* is boarding, and yet you're claiming that they face no impediment to flat-out *refusing* boarding? This clearly needs further qualificantion.

Comment: @Acccumulation I've never heard of an airline facing fines for delays in boarding—for late arrivals perhaps, or tarmac delays, but boarding? In any case, the airline can certainly withhold services if they believe the passenger is not or will not live up to his/her side of the contract in some way (for instance, by failing to have adequate documents or status in the judgment of the airline staff). They can be wrong, and after the fact they may face penalties of one sort or another, but you can't exactly call the police to force the airline to let you board in the moment.

Comment: @Acccumulation I didn't say there would not be any consequences for denying boarding. They may be required to refund and/or compensate you. But having a ticket doesn't mean you can force them to let you board. In most jurisdictions, the captain has ultimate authority over who is allowed on the aircraft.

Comment: @reirab I'm aware of the existence of the Schengen area, but Switzerland is a bit peculiar in its implementation of Schengen rules and it does not fully comply with freedom of movement (a separate issue, I'm aware, but it has an impact on their visa and entry policies). Requiring an onward ticket at entry is not part of the Schengen border code, so my assumption is that rule is part of Swiss law. Therefore, there's no reason to think an onward ticket out of Schengen and not Switzerland specifically is required. In fact, I can't find any reference to this rule outside of Timatic.

Comment: Is it a different question then whether it's possible to take legal action against the airline where you can prove they were wrong and you were admissible (like OP was)?

Comment: @MJeffryes Even for U.S. citizens entering France, Timatic says, "Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry," which is the same thing is says about Switzerland. It's not an absolute disqualifying factor, of course, but they'll want to see some kind of evidence that you intend to leave if you're arriving on visa-free entry. This is pretty normal for most countries, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @MJeffryes: It's a bit more complicated than just accessing Timatic at the checking desk, actually. In Europe, it's likely the airline is using Amadeus, and specifically the Amadeus DCS. In the Amadeus DCS, the airline must enter the rules in Amadeus system -- generally translating Timatic rules -- and then the rules held in the Amadeus system are used to tell the agent whether a passenger is eligible or not. I've seen airlines making mistakes (the system is complicated) or simply not bothering with the edge-cases (erring on the side of refusing)...

Comment: @MJeffryes: ... I would not be surprised if an agent were initially refusing boarding just based on the application they have; it may be worth asking if they can check Timatic directly if refused and believing you should be allowed to go.

Answer (score 13):

To give you an idea of what the airline agent is looking at in the airport, [here](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=timatic)'s a Timatic web interface which United Airlines provide:

[image]

And once you click on the Check button, you will get:

[image]

Note that if you change the "Ticket" field to "Return ticket held", the admission summary changes from "No" to "Conditional".

Answer (score 10):

> My question is, to what extent do airlines have the right to reject people from boarding due to immigration issues at the destination country?

They have *all the rights*. The airplane is *their own private property*. They don't need any justification to deny you boarding, they can allow or not allow anyone to enter their private property, as they please.

Yes, you did enter into a transportation contract with them, but the fine print in that contract will say something like this.

> My logic is that even if I landed in Switzerland without a residency permit and don't manage to acquire the necessary documents then, it should be the responsibility of the Swiss immigrations to kick me out of their country, and not the airline's (which isn't even swiss airlines)?

That is not correct. According to international treaties, it is the responsibility of the *airline* to ensure that you will be admitted into the country. In case you are denied entry, the airline has to both pay a hefty fine *and* return you to the airport of origin *at their cost*. (Although note that the transportation contract with you will also specify that they will recover the fine and this cost from you.)

If you had been denied entry, the airline would have had to pay a fine on the order of 10000$, and fly you back. They then, in turn, would have charged you with 10000$ + the cost of the return ticket, and they would have been completely within their rights to do so.

> […] a recent relaxation of regulation allows me to apply for a residency permit only after landing in Switzerland

Airline gate agents are not international immigration lawyers. They don't have the recent relaxations of all 41412 combinations of origin and destination countries memorized.

They rely on an automated system called *Timatic* which simply tells them "Yes" or "No". The information in Timatic is maintained based on information from the destination country. So, in this case, Switzerland has put into Timatic that entering without residency permit is not allowed, and that's the only information the gate agent has at their disposal.

> I argued with the manager for a while and eventually they let me board after I provided enough evidence that I had sufficient reason to be living in Switzerland and as a result I almost missed my flight.

You were lucky.

Moral of the story: Don't rely on gate agents being aware of every recent change in every immigration law of every country. Make life easy for them.

Even if you are right, *arguing* the fact that you are right may almost certainly take longer than the airplane is going to wait for you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110132/discussion-on-answer-by-jorg-w-mittag-what-rights-do-airlines-have-to-deny-board).